# Headphones connected event(or check) in Universal Windows Platform

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-desktop

I need to catch an event when headphones are connected to tablet or desktop PC in my UWP app. ARM version of the app(for Mobile family of UWP devices) catches such event as `Windows.Phone.Media.Devices.AudioRoutingManager.GetDefault().AudioEndpointChanged` event. Is there anything similar for x86 and x64 apps?

Comment: Hi, did you see this post?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538007/how-to-detect-unplugged-headphone-jack-in-winrt

Comment: @danny just checked it and still not sure what the real answer is. Will it work if I use information from the link provided there http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.createwatcher ?

Comment: I did not test it but I heard that it should work.

Comment: @danny Alright, thanks! Will try it and post an update

Comment: @danny Awesome, that solution worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am happy :) if I could ask to vote for my comment I would be grateful, thanks! ;)

Comment: @danny Already done it ;)